# Is there any way to detect if system clears the Caches directory?

Tags: ios, objective-c, caching, nsfilemanager

On app loading I save some data on `Caches` directory within application sandbox. Files name and/or amount may vary, so I cannot check using those. Sometimes system clears that `Caches` directory which causes my app to act unexpectedly, including crash. My questions are:

- When does system clears `Caches` directory?
- How can I detect that system cleared that directory?

Thanks you.

### Edit

From Apple's documentation:

> `Caches`
>
> Use this directory to write any app-specific support files that your app can re-create easily. Your app is generally responsible for managing the contents of this directory and for adding and deleting files as needed.
>
> In iOS 2.2 and later, the contents of this directory are not backed up by iTunes. In addition, iTunes removes files in this directory during a full restoration of the device.
>
> On iOS 5.0 and later, the system may delete the Caches directory on rare occasions when the system is very low on disk space. This will never occur while an app is running. However, you should be aware that iTunes restore is not necessarily the only condition under which the Caches directory can be erased.

Reference:[link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010672-CH2-SW1)

As I got my first answer, let me narrow down the second one:

- Is there any system file or flag which I can check to detect if system cleared the `Caches` directory?

Comment: No, so place your own file in Caches directory and check its existence periodically. ( But I don't recommend it, there must be another way. )

Comment: As I said, I don't know number of files and name of the files that store in `Caches` directory. It is maintained from server side with SOAP service and has an implementation of using it dynamically too. Anyway, thank you for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use the `Caches` directory to store critical data. It can be cleared at any time. Check out the docs for more info: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html

Comment: Actually, data I'm storing there are needed to be refreshed too. So, if I can detect that those are been cleared then I can re-download too. I also thought of `NSTimer` to clear it manually, but I want to do it with system cycle.